# Boot graphical application straight from Linux bootup (without verbose boot messages and desktop)

Tags: linux, boot, x11, console

Is it possible to boot from minimum Linux core(Linux/Android) to an application (preferably created in interchangeable platform languages such as C# – Mono / GTK / Java / C) without any verbose Linux boot messages on screen?

Basically power-on the OS and see nothing except your GUI application (no Linux messages, no desktop).

I would hope to do this on a well established simple platform, perhaps Linux, Android or even Chrome or any other options which makes even more sense.

What options is most easily or most appropriate. (for the sake of simplicity and reduce production time).

The purpose is to create a single purpose application on a PC/Raspberry pi/embedded (similar to XBMC or any other media application that serves as a single purpose device).

Comment: Some distributions (including Fedora) AFAIK avoid verbose boot by default (but you can recover it via a key stroke). You may want to use such a distro as a starting point or look at the tools that it uses to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible.

This is how a typical computer with linux boots -

```
BIOS -> 
Bootloader -> 
Linux Kernel -> 
INIT runs start-up scripts -> 
Login Screen -> 
Desktop Environment and / or Windows Manager
```

Basically when the computer starts, it looks for a boot loader. In case of Linux this is popularly either GRUB or LILO. GRUB or LILO then load the Linux Kernel. The kernel detects the hardware and loads the appropriate drivers, mounts your drives and does all the other stuff a kernel is supposed to do. It also runs the init program which is also responsible for creating other process, based on the start-up scripts.

Read more here: [Linux startup process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process)

Coming back to your question, all that boot / info messages that you see are generated during each phase of booting. BIOS will show splash screen, bootloader gives you option to select Kernel etc. and so on.

Just check the manual / documentation of each of these (the boot loader, the kernel, the start-up scripts etc.) that is used in the distro of linux that you are using, and check if they have an option / configuration to turn off these messages. (If they don't have an option, you might have to re-write those scripts so that these messages are not displayed.) And finally change / create a start-up script that runs your GUI program as soon as your linux kernel runs init.

Tip: Checkout [Debian Net Install](http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/). It is a bare minimum base linux system. (Just install it without an internet connection).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

You can launch GUI app without desktop environment. For example, you wanna launch chrome. The basic idea is creating a `chrome.desktop` in `/usr/share/xsessions/` like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Web Browser
Comment=Use a web browser as your session
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome --auto-launch-at-startup
TryExec=/usr/bin/google-chrome --auto-launch-at-startup
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
```

This wiki may be helpful.

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_manager#Starting_applications_without_a_window_manager